# docker compose build does not find file

Tags: docker-compose

I know it is a common problem but I do not find any solution it.
I want to create an Nginx reverse proxy server on Docker.
I go along this site [link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-nginx-reverse-proxy) but docker compose build returns a 'no configuration file provided' message or I add the location of the docker-compose.yml file 'no such file or directory'.
I try this:
sudo docker compose --file /example1/docker-compose.yml build
Output
stat /example1/docker-compose.yml: no such file or directory

The composer version is 2.17.2
I do not understand.